# QGIS Server not working (problem with fast CGI)

Tags: mapserver, references, qgis-server

Is there a simple example/tutorial of how to set up QGIS Server  with the latest QGIS version on Ubuntu, I can't get a correct result (blank image)?
I think there might be some problem with my FASTCGI config on apache.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using. Some issues installing on 11.04 were reported: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2011-May/012063.html

Comment: iam using 10.04

Comment: I did follow all the tutorials mentioned above, but I can not get qgis server work on Ubuntu lucid.
I can correctly visualize the capabilities and can see also the legends correctly but the getMap request returns a blank jpg or png.
Any help?

Answer (score 7):

I have it working on Ubuntu 10.04/10.10 and 11.04. My first tutorial was this

http://linfiniti.com/2010/08/qgis-mapserver-a-wms-server-for-the-masses/
(broken link)

but under Ubuntu (with all installed from repos) is even easier.

Enter the cgi-bin folder, create a project folder, copy in there the project file and a copy of qgis_mapserv.fcgi, then add a metadata file.

The qgis project MUST be saved with absolute paths (for layers).

Comment: i have done it seeing the same link two days ago.  but i got a white blank image instead of map even when http://localhost/cgi-bin/world/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities this is working,  wat do you mean by paths for layers?

Comment: yes, path for layers. Where you get blank images? in the desktop gis? in the browser?

Comment: i got blank images in firefox browser.  where do i specify paths for the layers?

Comment: in the project properties, general tab, "save paths" option.

Comment: wat about the blank images?

Comment: did you tested the WMS service you just created in QGIS? It give you blank images? any error message? What is the URL you are using to request images in the browser?

Comment: http://localhost/cgi-bin/world/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=78.7792,79.572,10.1251,11.1774&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=1077&HEIGHT=552&LAYERS=Continent,Country,Cities&STYLES=,,&FORMAT=image/jpeg&DPI=96

Comment: how to test wms service ? no error message.

Comment: how to test in QGIS? QGIS has a full WMS client: open it, create a connection, connect to the server, select the layer and then click OK.

Comment: i didnt get you :( ,what i need is to able to see the qgis maps from a client's browser

Comment: what you didn't get? How to connect and see WMS layers in QGIS?

Comment: This works for me: http://62.28.128.126:8080/cgi-bin/qgismapserver/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=-197951.5914222053543199,-310068.1141719180159271,232833.9803417159128003,286125.4196142427972518&CRS=EPSG:3763&WIDTH=1077&HEIGHT=552&LAYERS=CRIF2010&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96

Comment: yeah i need something like that  i get a blank image when i do that  wat did u put in BBOX settting?

Comment: can you please check if the WMS server is working using a friendly interface such like the one of QGIS?

Comment: iam able to connect to other wms servers

Comment: and YOUR wms server? any error messages? can you see your layer list and see one of them in a QGIS project?

Comment: how can i test my own wms server ?

Comment: If you are using QGIS-Mapserver I guess that the best choice would be using QGIS, isn't it? See above comments. In QGIS you have a WMS client, it is easy. If don't know how to set up a WMS connection in QGIS just look at the manual, then report back.

Comment: did you tested your qgis-wms server with a desktop client? it works?

Comment: desktop client? how to test it on browser?

Comment: yesm desktop client... A GIS Desktop program. Once again, use QGIS, considered you are trying to set up a WMS server with QGIS!

Comment: how to setup an wms server with qgis?

Comment: qgis 1.6 manual (english version), page 77

Comment: Hi guys, you could use the GIS chat for your discussions and come back with the answer if found.

Comment: i cannot use the chat as i dont have enough reputaion :(

Comment: And I'm not chatting, I'm trying to help ;)

Answer (score 2):

QGIS Server main documentation is located at: http://www.qgis.org/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial

Quoting the Wiki section for Ubuntu:

To setup QGIS Server with Apache 2 mod_fastcgi, the following packages are required: 
**apt-get install qgis-mapserver libapache2-mod-fcgid**

Note that libapache2-mod-fcgid and libapache2-mod-fastcgi are different packages and require different configurations.

Using the default configuration, QGIS Server should answer a GetCapabilities request from here:

http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Answer (score 2):

I installed qgis and qgis_server using this tutorial:
http://underdark.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/qgis-server-on-ubuntu-step-by-step/

Characteristics:

- Ubuntu 12.04.O
- Virtual Machine

  1. In "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/" create a folder called "test" ."test" is where you will save your qgis project and .shp too. Inside  this folder you must copy the file qgis_mapserv.fcgi and the wms_metadata.xml too.
  2. Open a .shp file in qgis and save it as a project in  "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/test/". Let's suppose you project name is "demo.qgis"
  3. Now in project properties define your src as Google Mercator and in layer properties define your layer name and save it.
  4. After that, close you project and create a new one.
  5. In the new blank project , add a WMS layer and add the name and the url of your project name.

Example (step 5):

```
      Name: Rivers
      url://http://localhost/cgi-bins/test/qgis_mapserv.fcgi
```

and then accept and voila...