# QGIS project on QGIS server -- cannot load wms layer

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-server

I've created a qgis project on QGIS 1.8, copied it onto the QGIS Server, and am trying to load the project as a WMS Layer back into QGIS. There is one vector layer in the project. Paths have been set to absolute and the CRS for both the layer and project is EPSG 27700.

In the "Add Layer(s) from a Server" dialog box, the project is showing, but not the vector layer. Clicking on the project, at the bottom of the dialog box it says "No Common CRS for selected layers".

Any help is very welcome -- I have searched the forums and tried the solutions suggested [QGIS Server Capabilities Response doesn't contain any Layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14806/qgis-server-capabilities-response-doesnt-contain-any-layers) and [QGIS Server Capabilities Response doesn't contain any Layers (Fedora 15 64-bit)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15684/qgis-server-capabilities-response-doesnt-contain-any-layers-fedora-15-64-bit) but still cannot get it to work.

Many thanks!