# qgis-mapserver: GetCapabilities returns no layer

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-server, getcapabilities

My problem is similar to 
[this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14806/qgis-server-capabilities-response-doesnt-contain-any-layers)

I've installed QGIS 2.4 and QGIS server 2.4 on Fedora. I created a simple project containing a vector layer (shapefiles)
GetCapabilities request works but there is no layer in it. Except the Layer tag containing the name of the project.

Example:

```
<Layer queryable="1"> 
<Name>test3</Name> 
<Title>test3</Title> 
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox> 
<westBoundLongitude>-68.5</westBoundLongitude> 
<eastBoundLongitude>-68.5</eastBoundLongitude> 
<southBoundLatitude>44</southBoundLatitude> 
<northBoundLatitude>44</northBoundLatitude> 
</EX_GeographicBoundingBox> 
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:32198" maxx="0" minx="0" maxy="0" miny="0"/> 
</Layer>
```

here is an example of my query

```
http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=test3.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

I tried in the browser and curl command line and got the same result.

All the characters in the path are ascii. 
Perhaps it is a privilege access problem but I could not resolve it. My path is readable by all, since GetCapablities works it can read my .qgs.

Any idea on what the problem is?

Comment: I think it is a bug. qgis desktop use relative path for layers data. So in .qgs I get <datasource>./echantillonage.shp</datasource> If I manually set an absolute path GetCapablities returns my layers. I'll get on qgis dev list

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug, there is a property to set the path absolute
http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11509

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a problem.  The purpose of the GetCapabilites response is to tell you the name of the layers and the operations available though the service.

You need to construct a GetMap request to get the data.